# Objective C - how to access a file from iPhone/Application/Documents

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am using the following method to write image files out to the Applications/Documents folder:

```
- (void)saveImage:(UIImage *)image toFile:(NSString *)fileName
{
    //get the data from the representation
    NSData * binaryImageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);

    NSArray * paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString * basePath = ([paths count] > 0) ? [paths objectAtIndex:0] : nil;

    //write the data to a file
    [binaryImageData writeToFile:[basePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName] atomically:YES];
}
```

I thought I could just copy them to my computer, but that's not working out for me.  Then, I decided to try to write the files to my hard drive.  Nope.  I guess that was a dumb idea, too.

I am processing bitmap images that I just want to capture somewhere (**not on the device**) where I can then retrieve them for testing.  I've mucked with this for several hours and now it's getting late and I'm tired.  Definitely ready for a little help.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you want to copy files from your iphone/ipad to your computer?

Comment: [[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtURL:originURL toURL:saveURL error:NULL]; did you used this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to use images from device to your computer... you have to enable file sharing option in your app... When you enable it from your app's info.plist file you can see document folder in itunes.

Select you app from list and then, You can put & get files to/from document directory.

[image]

if you want to access image from document directory in app so you can use this method.

```
-(UIImage *)getImageFromDocumentDirectoryForFileName:(NSString *)fileName
{
    NSArray * paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString * basePath = ([paths count] > 0) ? [paths objectAtIndex:0] : nil;

    UIImage *image =[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[basePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName]];

    return image;
}
```

Comment: Great info!  There were a few hoops I had to complete to get this working for me, so I'll add an additional post.  But definitely, you answered this question.  Thank you.  :-)

Answer (score 2):

**This question was answered by Rajesh Choudhary**, but there were a few more hoops to go through to get the images off the phone and I wanted to post the entire process to help someone else in the future.  So, here are the steps.

- Enable file sharing from your app's info.plist file:

[image: Application supports iTunes file sharing]

- Use the code in the original post to write the file out to the
  application /Documents folder.
- Run your app to save the file to the iPhone application /Documents folder.
- Check that your files were save by opening **Organizer** and selecting the iPhone running the application and selecting the application.  The saved files will be located in the **Documents** folder in **Data files in Sandbox**.
- To access them, open **iTunes**.  Select the device running the application and select the **Apps** tab.  Then, scroll to the **File Sharing** section, select the app and voila!  The documents folder will display all your saved files on the device.
- You can then select one or more of the files and click the **Save to...** button to save the files to your computer.